# Why do short hairs get longer with age?

Tags: growth, hair

I know that short hairs such as eyebrows, eyelashes, nasal hairs will stay a certain length because the lifespan of the follicle only allows them to grow to a certain length.

My question is why do those hairs start to grow longer and longer with age?